# NetworkOnMainThreadException on retrieving file from input stream and opening it as PDF

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below is the code which is basically owrking...well mostly. It works on all phones I was testing, but fails on the client phone, I can't use. Which part of this code could cause NetworkOnMainThreadException?

It's really straight forward. What I do in onPostExecute() is:

1. Geting InputStream from onBackground()
2. Aborting if InputStream is null, aborting if null.
3. Checking external storage avalibility, aborting if not.
4. Creating file from InputStream
5. Checking PDF viewer avalibility, aborting if not avalible
6. Opening newly created PDF

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(InputStream is) {
       super.onPostExecute(is);
       if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
       }

       if (is== null) {
           errorMessage = getString(R.string.error_server_communication);
           CustomDialogs.showErrorDialog( fragment.getActivity(), getString( R.string.error_title ), errorMessage );
           return;
       }

       //checking external storage avalibility
       if (!Tools.isWriteableExternalStorageAvalible()) {
           errorMessage = getString(R.string.error_no_external_storage);
           CustomDialogs.showErrorDialog( fragment.getActivity(), getString( R.string.error_title ), errorMessage );
           return;
       }               

       // opening pdf
       try {
           File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp");
           if (!directory.exists())
               directory.mkdirs();

           File file = new File(directory, "file.pdf");

           //usuwa poprzednio przechowywany wynik jesli taki byl
           if (file.exists()) 
               file.delete();

           file.createNewFile();                   

           // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
           OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           out.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));

           is.close();
           out.flush();
           out.close();

           if (Tools.canDisplayPdf(fragment.getActivity())) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
               startActivity( intent );
           } else {
               //user nie ma przegladarki pdf - komunikat
               errorMessage = getString(R.string.error_server_communication);
               CustomDialogs.showErrorDialog( fragment.getActivity(), getString( R.string.error_title ), errorMessage );
           }

       } catch (IOException e) {
           errorMessage = getString(R.string.error_server_communication);
           CustomDialogs.showErrorDialog( fragment.getActivity(), getString( R.string.error_title ), errorMessage );
       }
   }
   ```

Also including a stack trace. There is one more clue. Client is retrieving InputStream using SSL, and I'm not. Unfortunately can't debug it with SSL yet.

```
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:668)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:174)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:188)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:178)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1383)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1357)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:361)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at pl.luxmed.pp.activities.MedicalExaminationsActivity$OpenPdfAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MedicalExaminationsActivity.java:270)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at pl.luxmed.pp.activities.MedicalExaminationsActivity$OpenPdfAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MedicalExaminationsActivity.java:1)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-05 21:34:02.648: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's on line 270 of MedicalExaminationsActivity.java?

Comment: it's out.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(is)); do we have a winner? :)

Comment: I think so. Check if any part of that statement needs a network connection and I think you'll have solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though you are using `AsyncTask`, its `onPostExecute()` method is executed on UI thread (to let you update your views etc). Actually, the only method of `AsyncTask` executed in separate thread is `doInBackground()`, so you have to perform all operations involving I/O (disk, network), only in this method, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for details.

Comment: Weird it's working on most phones. Please see my step by step list. Could you tell me which steps should I move to onBackground()?

Comment: @Xylian - what's on line 270  of MedicalExaminationsActivity.java?

Comment: @Xylian As far as I see at some point you get the URI of your PDF file. So perform all file operations you need to get it in `doInBackground()` return the URI from it, and then try to view it in `onPostExecute()` (check if viewer is available, start intents, notify user etc).

Comment: @Xylian And yes, NetworkOnMainThreadException was introduced in 2.3.3, as Coder mentioned in his answer, so older versions of Android will not throw it.

Comment: Reworked my code, so onBackground() pases URL to the file, and it holds most of the operation. Only opening is now held by onPostExecute - waiting on the client feedback, but I hope it went well

Comment: @Xylian even you can not open URL. :)..Please accept answer if my answer help you in anyway

Comment: what about opening new intent with pdf file? I can do that on postExecute right?

Comment: @Coder URI you see in the `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");` line of code  has nothing to do with network (it points to the local file). The source of `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is line 270 of `MedicalExaminationsActivity.java`

Comment: @deville i never says that it related to NetworkOnMainThreadException. I just explain him what NetworkOnMainThreadException. So that he can know the exact reason. I talked about URL not URI .Intent can be used there

Comment: @Xylian yes, you definitely can. You're not actually opening a PDF, you're just starting an intent.

Answer (score 3):

From the Android Doc **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** clearly stated that from `android 2.3.3` you can not call URL in main UI thread. Please cross check it and make sure you did not do this mistake

**From Android Developer**

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or highe.